# Apache Storm FileNotFoundException in Cluster Mode

Tags: java, docker, apache-storm

I've tried to deploy a storm topology in cluster (distributed) mode. Unfortunately I got a `FileNotFoundException` and I can't find any mistake that I have made. I would be great if you could help me to figure out what is wrong.

I'm using Storm version 1.0.1. Zookeeper ist running on an extra VM.

The following stack trace occurs:

> [{:type java.lang.RuntimeException    :message java.io.IOException: No
>   such file or directory    :at
>   [org.apache.storm.blobstore.LocalFsBlobStore createBlob
>   LocalFsBlobStore.java 117]}   {:type java.io.IOException    :message
>   No such file or directory    :at [java.io.UnixFileSystem
>   createFileExclusively UnixFileSystem.java -2]}]  :trace 
>   [[java.io.UnixFileSystem createFileExclusively UnixFileSystem.java -2]
>   [java.io.File createNewFile File.java 1012]
>   [org.apache.storm.blobstore.LocalFsBlobStoreFile getOutputStream
>   LocalFsBlobStoreFile.java 109]
>   [org.apache.storm.blobstore.BlobStore$BlobStoreFileOutputStream 
>   BlobStore.java 316]   [org.apache.storm.blobstore.LocalFsBlobStore
>   createBlob LocalFsBlobStore.java 111]
>   [org.apache.storm.blobstore.BlobStore createBlob BlobStore.java 217]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it for my case, hopefully this is also a solution for your one.

The files the storm installation wants to write are in the local blob store, located in `storm.local.dir` + `/blobs` (by default, that's `storm-local/blobs` in the directory where you installed Storm) . You should check if the permissions match the user you use to run Storm.

In my case it turns out that the user and group information in my Systemd service-file came after the exec and thus it didn't work. If you also use Systemd for starting nimbus, use this template:

```
[Unit]
Description=start and stop storm nimbus
After=network.target

[Service]
User=storm
Group=storm
WorkingDirectory=/home/storm/apache-storm-1.0.2
ExecStart=/home/storm/apache-storm-1.0.2/bin/storm nimbus
Restart=on-failure
```

Comment: For me it was the files under storm.local.dir + /blobs that were owned by root and we run storm as a different user.